# Enterprise (802.1x) WiFi causing excessive battery drain?

Tags: wi-fi, battery-life

In the past week, realised that WiFi at work (using 802.1x auth) has been draining my battery like crazy.

Here are some stats I took over the past few days:

```
Case   Connection       Duration     Battery left
 A      802.1x Wifi      ~10hrs          0%
 B      3G               ~17hrs         46%
 C      WPA2 Wifi        ~1d 11hrs      34%
```

In all three cases, usage was light: occasional checking of email, sms or two, short phone call etc. If anything, probably used the phone more in case B&C - played some light games.

The odd thing is this crazy battery drain has only been happening in the past week or so - used to be at 20% after ~15hours when connected to 802.1x Wifi.

Does anyone know why Enterprise/802.1x WiFi is causing significant battery drain?

edit: Device details - HTC Desire running Nikez 4.2.1 (Evervolv-Turba-3.2.0p3)

edit2: Screenshots: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9907360/battery/battery.html

Comment: it would be nice to tell us info about your device. I suppose all those problems are device specific (or ROM for specific device). My experiences with device Samsung Galaxy S2 and Huawei G300 shows that there is not that much big difference between battery usage on 802.1x and WPA2-PSK. ~ Jiri

Comment: Details added. Not convinced if it has to do with ROM/phone, since I was running this configuration for over a month, and battery draining problem is only from the past week or so.

Comment: Have you installed anything special when this problem started to occur? Could you paste a screen of your battery stats? Imho, I found out that many custom ROMs based on Jelly Bean 4.2 have serious problems with battery drain.

Comment: Updated question with link to screenshots. No apps/nothing special that jumps to mind - possibly upgraded SwiftKey around that timeframe. Puzzling thing is whatever it is, it is definitely only affecting Enterprise/802.1x WiFi (and only in the recent few weeks - so likely not ROM)

Comment: I have confirmed on my own network that 802.1x causes excessive battery drain. I have AP's with 2 SSID's. One is 802.1x and one is OPEN. I get 6% and hour drain on 802.1x and 2% on OPEN. Not sure if it keeps authenticating to the RADIUS or what is causing the issue. I would LOVE for someone to resolve this as 802.1x has so many other benefits.